# How do i avoid referencing DataLayer in UI layer?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, architecture

I have a project with 3 layers. UI, Business Layer and Data Layer.

UI calls BL. BL Calls DL. DL does the database operations. its that simple.

I wanted to unit test my BL methods so i changed it a bit and now i am accepting DL as a parameter in the BL constructor so that i can create Mock object of DL.

This makes me change my UI layer as my UI calls my BL and as per architecture rules i think its not a good design if i add reference of my DL to my UI.

Can someone suggest a better way? Do i need to change the architecture or am i doing something wrong here? May be i can introduce Facade Manager here? An example of your suggestion will be highly appreciated.

--Edit--

Here is the code:

in BL:

```
    public MyBusinessLayer()
    {

    }
    //To pass mock object of WCF Service
    public MyBusinessLayer(ISomeServices svc)
    {
        someServiceRef = svc;
    }

    //To pass mock object of Data Layer.
    public MyBusinessLayer(ISomeDataLayer dl)
    {
        someDlRef = dl;
    }
```

in UI:

```
//To do this i have to add DL reference to UI
MyBusinessLater b = new MyBusinessLayer(new ISomeService());
```

Comment: How about showing some code of what you're doing?

Comment: I can create Manager class and refer it in UI layer and add BL and DL references to it but again i am not feeling comfortabel with adding BL and DL references to the same (manager) class. I want DL to be refenced only in BL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IoC would be perfect for this job. Your BL should only rely on an interface that can get the data it needs. Then, using IoC, register the actual DB implementation with the interface. The UI should then get injected with an interfaced BL. Therefore, when the app starts up, you register all the dependencies, and just inject the BL interface into the UI, so the UI has no knowledge of the fact that the actual BL implementation relies on a DL interface.

Here's just on example I found on the net. Just google for C# IOC or C# Dependency Injection.
http://www.dotnetspark.com/kb/266-inversion-control-ioc-and-dependency-injection.aspx

Comment: I know IoC but the problem is i cant use it in the project. i know its too bad but cant do anything there.

Comment: @Asdfg - You're already using IoC (for example passing ISomeServices to the MyBusinessLayer constructor). You don't have to use an IoC Container framework.

Comment: @TrueWill - I am able to do that because my ISomeServices interface resides in BL. problem is my ISomeDataLayer interface resides in DL. In order to use that, it says i have to add DataLayer reference to my UI. Do i need to create separate project for ISomeDataLayer interface and add it to my UI layer? Will that not be considered as adding DL reference to UI?

Comment: @Asdfg - In general you will want to create a separate project for the shared interfaces. If you're reasonably sure that the implementation will not change and you're mainly doing this for testability, you could leave the interfaces in the DL for now. Adding interfaces to the UI is not the same as adding concrete DL class references. That said, I think what you want is an interfaced BL as @BFree suggested. So the BL gets the DL interface, and the UI gets only the BL interface.

Comment: @TrueWill - Ok. this is what i did. I remove the DL interface from the DL project and put it in the separate assembly and referenced it from my UI and my Unit test project. Problem is fixed. And as you said referencing interface is not the same thing as adding concrete DL, i think i am good. I will do the same thing with my BL. Please do let me know if i am on the wrong track. Thanks a lot for the help. Much appreciated.

Comment: I would actually put the interface to the DAL in the same assembly as the BLL. The DAL assembly references the BLL to implement the interface. This is known as the dependency inversion principle. As you can't use a IoC framework, just use reflection at runtime to interrogate the types in the DAL assembly to find the one that implements your interface and instantiate it, then pass it into your BLL.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to put all the data types in a seperate dll.

Then reference this dll from UI, BL and DAL.

Then there is no need for the UI to reference the DAL.

Answer (score 0):

@BFree's answer is correct; I'm just answering to clarify my comments. Here's what I'd recommend (which I believe is the same that @BFree is recommending):

```
public class MyBusinessLayer : IBusinessLayer
{
    public MyBusinessLayer(ISomeDataLayer dl, ISomeServices svc) {}
}

public class MyUI
{
    public MyUI(IBusinessLayer bl) {}
}
```

Whether you're using MVC, MVVM, or whatever, something somewhere is creating your user interface (or the controller thereof). That method gets to know about everything, since it wires everything up. Everything else only knows about interfaces.

I'd be more concerned about references to concrete types in other layers (coupling) than about assembly references in your projects.